# Signals Over Long Wires using raspberry pi 3 model b

Tags: gpio, pi-3, i2c

I have a pi 3 b with me, The task is to control relay modules to switch on and off the lights for my entire building from my office . In my building I have almost 16 rooms and far most room is about 200 feet away from the pi, so how to connect them to my raspberry pi and how to access them ?
Is i2c will work for this ?
or is their any other way to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. This might be of interest for you: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/106265/52154 ... they seem to claim that I2C could work the distance. If it does not work I suggest to look into RS485

Comment: Are there no safety implications?  What you propose doing sounds pretty dodgy to me.